# Differences between struct in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, kmdf

I am trying to convert a C++ struct to C but keep getting "undeclared identifier"?  Does C++ have a different syntax for referring to structs?

```
struct KEY_STATE 
{
    bool kSHIFT; //if the shift key is pressed 
    bool kCAPSLOCK; //if the caps lock key is pressed down
    bool kCTRL; //if the control key is pressed down
    bool kALT; //if the alt key is pressed down
};
```

I am using a variable of type KEY_STATE inside another structure:

```
typedef struct _DEVICE_EXTENSION
{
    WDFDEVICE WdfDevice;
    KEY_STATE kState;
} DEVICE_EXTENSION, *PDEVICE_EXTENSION;
```

results in  **error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'KEY_STATE'**

...on the line **KEY_STATE kState;** I am building with the WDK compiler if that makes any difference. This is in a header file of course. I am porting C++ WDM driver to WDF and C.

[This is the MSDN article for C2061](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yha416c7%28VS.80%29.aspx).

> An initializer may be enclosed by parentheses. To avoid this problem, enclose the declarator in parentheses or make it a typedef.
>
> This error could also be caused when the compiler detects an expression as a class template argument; use typename to tell the compiler it is a type.

Changing KEY_STATE to typedef struct still causes this error and actually causes a lot more. There are no free parentheses or things in too many parentheses, that is the other thing the article suggests.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In C, the name of the type is `struct KEY_STATE`.

So you have to declare the second struct as

```
typedef struct _DEVICE_EXTENSION
{
    WDFDEVICE WdfDevice;
    struct KEY_STATE kState;
} DEVICE_EXTENSION, *PDEVICE_EXTENSION;
```

If you do not want to write `struct` all the time, you can use a typedef declare `KEY_STATE` similar to `DEVICE_EXTENSION`:

```
typedef struct _KEY_STATE
{
    /* ... */
} KEY_STATE;
```

Answer (score 16):

There is no `bool` type in C prior to C99.

Also, there is no type called `KEY_STATE` when you do `struct KEY_STATE`.

Try this instead:

```
typedef struct _KEY_STATE 
{
    unsigned kSHIFT : 1; //if the shift key is pressed 
    unsigned kCAPSLOCK : 1; //if the caps lock key is pressed down
    unsigned kCTRL : 1; //if the control key is pressed down
    unsigned kALT : 1; //if the alt key is pressed down
} KEY_STATE;
```

Comment: +1 thanks, the bool was causing a bunch more errors I didn't really understand

Answer (score 6):

You need to refer to `KEY_STATE` with `struct KEY_STATE`. In C++ you can leave the `struct` out, but not in plain C.

Another solution is to do a type alias:

`typedef struct KEY_STATE KEY_STATE`

Now `KEY_STATE` means the same thing as `struct KEY_STATE`

Answer (score 5):

You could/should typedef the struct so that you don't need the struct keyword every time you will declare a variable of that type.

```
typedef struct _KEY_STATE 
{
    bool kSHIFT; //if the shift key is pressed 
    bool kCAPSLOCK; //if the caps lock key is pressed down
    bool kCTRL; //if the control key is pressed down
    bool kALT; //if the alt key is pressed down
} KEY_STATE;
```

Now you can do:

```
KEY_STATE kState;
```

or (as in the example you have) :

```
struct KEY_STATE kState;
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to qualify a struct variable with the 'struct' keyword:

```
typedef struct _DEVICE_EXTENSION
{
    WDFDEVICE WdfDevice;
    struct KEY_STATE kState;
} DEVICE_EXTENSION, *PDEVICE_EXTENSION;
```

When you use DEVICE_EXTENSION you don't have to do use 'struct' because you are doing a struct definition and a typedef in a single compound statement. So you could do the same for KEY_STATE if you wanted to use it in a similar fasion:

```
typedef struct _KEY_STATE_t
{
    bool kSHIFT; //if the shift key is pressed 
    bool kCAPSLOCK; //if the caps lock key is pressed down
    bool kCTRL; //if the control key is pressed down
    bool kALT; //if the alt key is pressed down
} KEY_STATE;
```