# A way to do c++ "typedef struct foo foo;" for c

Tags: c++, c, gcc, typedef

Going by gcc version 4.4.2, it appears that saying

```
typedef struct foo foo;
// more code here - like function declarations taking/returning foo*
// then, in its own source file:
typedef struct foo
{
    int bar;
} foo;
```

is legal in C++ but not in C.

Of course I have a body of code that compiles fine in C++ by using the *foo* type but it appears I must make it use *struct foo* (in the header file) to get it to work with some C code another developer wrote.

Is there a way to predeclare a ***struct typedef foo foo*** in gcc C without getting a "redefinition of typedef 'foo'" error when compiling for C? (I don't want the marginally illegal and less clean underscore solution of ***struct typedef _foo foo***)

Comment: Duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492735/differences-between-struct-in-c-and-c/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the differences between C++ and C is that in C++ it is legal to make a repetitive `typedef` in the same scope as long as all these `typedef` are equivalent. In C repetitive `typedef` is illegal.

```
typedef int TInt;
typedef int TInt; /* OK in C++. Error in C */
```

This is what you have in your above code. If you are trying to write a code that can be compiled as both C and C++, get rid of the superfluous second typedef and just do

```
typedef struct foo foo;  
...
struct foo  
{  
    int bar;  
};
```

(although in C++ the first `typedef` is superfluous as well).

Comment: Success with that, just write `typedef struct foo foo` in a common header file or a forward-declaration header.

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you need?

```
// header (.h)
struct foo;
typedef struct foo foo;

foo *foo_create();
// etc.

// source (.c)
struct foo {
    // ...
}
```

I also tend to prefix my struct name with an underscore when typdefing to make its privateness clear and prevent possible name clashes.

Comment: beware reserved names when using underscores, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why GCC rejects this code, but it appears it only objects because you're defining the same typedef twice.

This works:

```
typedef struct foo foo;

struct foo {
    int bar;
};
```

And this works too, with the same effect:

```
typedef struct foo {
    int bar;
} foo;
```