# Assign int value to a pointer

Tags: c++, c, struct

I need to assign an int value to a pointer, how would I do it?

Below is a small example of what I want.

```
struct {
  int a;
} name;
int temp = 3;
struct name *obj = NULL;
```

Now, I need to assign this value '3' to struct's 'a'.

Comment: struct's a is not a pointer.

Comment: `name.a = temp;` or `name.a = 3;` done :)

Comment: how about no? name is a struct name.

Comment: Your `obj` isn't the type of that struct you defined. It's a new type. To prove it, take out the struct definition and the `obj` declaration still compiles.

Comment: Prefer object to pointer as you will get better performance and don't need to worry about memory management.

Comment: @billz shouldn't that be `->`?

Answer (score 4):

With

```
struct {
   int a;
}name;
```

you already define a struct variable which allocates memory for the struct (e.g. on the stack when it is a local variable inside a function). Then, with `int temp = 3;`, it is sufficient to assign to the struct member like

```
name.a = temp;
```

If you want to declare a struct **type** only, then use

```
struct name {
   int a;
};
```

Then you can define any number of struct variables based on this type, like

```
struct name theName;
```

and do the same assignment to `theName` members as above:

```
theName.a = temp;
```

Or, you can define a pointer to a struct and then have to allocate the memory yourself:

```
struct name *namePtr;
namePtr = malloc(sizeof(struct name));
namePtr->a = temp;
```

Note also that you have tagged your question both with `C` and `C++` - especially with structs, you should decide which language to take - see [Differences between struct in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492735/differences-between-struct-in-c-and-c).

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a pointer to a struct doesn't reserve memory for it, so first you have to do that. For example:

```
obj = malloc(sizeof(*obj));
```

Now you can assign the value:

```
obj->a = temp;
```

Note that the program as it currently stands does not define "struct name", it defines a variable called "name" that holds a struct. This is probably not what you intended.

Comment: You have to allocate the space for the `struct name` somehow.  `malloc` puts it on the heap, and says to allocate `sizeof *obj` (or, put another way, the size of `struct name`).  Alternately, you can allocate the struct on the stack without `malloc` as shown in my answer.

Comment: @joni I think billz means that `struct {...} name;` already allocates memory - note that this is different from `struct name {...};` which only declares the structure type

Comment: Very good point Andreas.  It should be declared `struct name {...};`

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem with the code is `name` is not the name of the structure but an object or a variable of the structure whose name you have already defined.

If u don't want to name the structure, even then still it need memory to be allocated.

```
struct
{
        int a;
}name, *obj;
int temp = 3;

int main()
{
        obj=&name;    // 'obj' is pointing to memory area of 'name' : Keep this in mind throughout the code 
        obj->a=temp;
        printf("%d %u %d",temp,&temp,obj->a);
        return 0;
}
```

Best option is to put a name to the structure then use its pointer after allocating memory

```
typedef struct
{
        int a;
}name;
int temp = 3;
name *obj = NULL;

int main()
{
        obj = (name *)malloc(sizeof(name));
        obj->a=temp;
        printf("%d %u %d",temp,&temp,obj->a);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (thanks Andreas):

Properly, your struct should be declared like so:

```
struct name {
    int a;
};

void foo() {
    struct name n;        // allocate space for 'struct name' and call it n
    struct name *obj;     // a pointer to a 'struct name'
    int temp = 3;    

    obj = &n;             // make obj point to n

    n.a = temp;           // direct assignment to a
    obj->a = temp;        // assignment to a via pointer dereference
                          // a is now 3 in any case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another, annotated, version of your code.  Ran this on Eclipse/Microsoft C compiler, this is NOT C++ code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
   // define a structure as a data type
   typedef struct
   {
     int *a;
   } name;

   // allocate storage for an integer and set it to 3
   int temp = 3;

   // allocate storage for the name structure
   name obj;

   // set the value of a in name to point to an integer
   obj.a = &temp;

   // dereference the integer pointer in the name structure
   printf("%d\n", *obj.a);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
obj->a = temp;
```

just have a try!